# Excel VBA to Outlook: error Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to write a VBA code in Excel that will create an Outlook message which contains:

1. text in the body
2. a table
3. a signature at the bottom.

Below is a code that I wrote.  It was working until I added the Excel `Table` object to the body of the message.  It's coming up with an error message that says:

> Run-time error: error type 13, Type Mismatch".

Can someone help with my code below?

```
Sub send()
  Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
  Dim TOEMAIL As Range
  Dim CCMEMAIL As Range
  Dim SUBJECT As Range
  Dim Workbook As Range
  Dim Table As Range


  Set TOEMAIL = Sheets("Macro").Range("D6")
  Set CCEMAIL = Sheets("Macro").Range("D7")
  Set SUBJECT = Sheets("Macro").Range("D8")
  Set Workbook = Sheets("Macro").Range("D5")
  Set Table = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:B17")

  Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
  With OMail
   .Display
  End With

  signature = OMail.body
  With OMail
   .To = TOEMAIL
   .CC = CCEMAIL
   .SUBJECT = SUBJECT
   .Attachments.Add (Workbook)
   .body = "Hello, this is a test." & vbNewLine & Table & vbNewLine & signature & vbNewLine
  End With
  Set OMail = Nothing
  Set OApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this site:  http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem.Body` property expects a string. You are trying to concatenate a few strings and a Range object. It is your responsibility to extract the relevant data from that table and represent it as a string.

You would probably be better off creating an HTML table and setting the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Given that I am still learning VBA, is there anyone interested in showing me how to do this for a small fee?...say $10.  Let me know.  Please email me your email address and I will send you the file that I have set up.  Thanks!